# Replacing multiple, different extensions in a single folder with .txt

Tags: python-3.x, file, file-extension

I've been trying to copy files from one directory to another and then changing all the files I moved into .txt files. The only problem is that there are multiple, probably 30+ different extensions and hard coding them is not an option because there could be different extensions in different output folders. I've been able to move all the files from one to another pretty easily, but being able to change every extension in a folder (.ser, .pbr, etc,) to a .txt has proven difficult. If anyone could help that would be great. This is my code for moving files from one folder to another so I just need to be able to change the files to .txt either while they are being moved or after they've been copied to the new folder.

src = 'L:/Development/DCS/UL/Dev\202209\1_202206_4355_4359/OUTPUT/202112'
trg = 'L:/Development/DCS/UL/Dev/Test Output'

```
files=os.listdir('L:/Development/DCS/UL/Dev/202209/1_202206_4355_4359/OUTPUT/202112')
 
# iterating over all the files in
# the source directory
for fname in files:   
    try:
    # copying the files to the
    # destination directory
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join('L:/Development/DCS/UL/Dev/202209/1_202206_4355_4359/OUTPUT/202112',fname), 'L:/Development/DCS/UL/Dev/Test Output')  
    except:
        print ("error")
    pass
```

Comment: Why does it matter what the file extension is if you change it to.txt anyway?

Comment: It doesn’t, but I’ve only seen code that will only do one extension to txt. Either for a single file or all files with the same ext. so there could be 15 .SER files that turn to .txt but there’s 30 of another one and so on and so forth that didn’t turn to .txt. I didn’t know if there was a way to convert all of them at once or if you could only write code to change certain file extensions and then create a new line changing another one and then create a new line changing another one, etc.. I tried an if statement with all the different files and it just didn’t work no matter what I did.